# Softlayer: Providing PEM file for accessing servers

Tags: pem, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Is it possible to create a common `pem` file in softlayer to access all the machines in on VLAN from UI itself.

I have looked in all the configuration panels but wasnt able to find this setting.
I wanted to check with other users who might have created `pem` file to keep a common access credential login in all the machines.

Answer (score 0):

I did not have the experience of working with this, but I can suggest to send an email to **PortalFeedBack@softlayer.com**, in order that they can provide more information about it or if it can be consider to implement.